# How do I export text from only certain shapes in ppt using VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to export text from a large ppt. I have figured out how to export but I get all text from all shapes and I'm only interested in certain text.

Is there a way to have an IF function that checks the formatting of the shape and grabs the text only if the IF function is true. I want to select text only from shapes with a dashed border. Is that possible?

This is the code I have

```
    Sub ExportText()

  Dim oPres As Presentation
  Dim oSlides As Slides
  Dim oSld As Slide         'Slide Object
  Dim oShp As Shape         'Shape Object
  Dim iFile As Integer      'File handle for output
  iFile = FreeFile          'Get a free file number
  Dim PathSep As String
  Dim FileNum As Integer

  #If Mac Then
    PathSep = ":"
  #Else
    PathSep = "\"
  #End If

  Set oPres = ActivePresentation
  Set oSlides = oPres.Slides

  FileNum = FreeFile

  'Open output file
  ' NOTE:  errors here if file hasn't been saved
  Open oPres.Path & PathSep & "AllText.TXT" For Output As FileNum

  For Each oSld In oSlides    'Loop thru each slide
    For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes                'Loop thru each shape on slide

      'Check to see if shape has a text frame and text
      If oShp.HasTextFrame And oShp.TextFrame.HasText Then
        If oShp.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
            Select Case oShp.PlaceholderFormat.Type
                Case Is = ppPlaceholderTitle, ppPlaceholderCenterTitle
                    Print #iFile, "Title:" & vbTab & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
                Case Is = ppPlaceholderBody
                    Print #iFile, "Body:" & vbTab & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
                Case Is = ppPlaceholderSubtitle
                    Print #iFile, "SubTitle:" & vbTab & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
                Case Else
                    Print #iFile, "Other Placeholder:" & vbTab & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
            End Select
        Else
            Print #iFile, vbTab & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
        End If  ' msoPlaceholder
      End If    ' Has text frame/Has text

    Next oShp
  Next oSld

  'Close output file
  Close #iFile

End Sub
```

Comment: first tip to you: you have already asked some questions, is there any answer which was good to you? If so, you could accept some of them which is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here goes solution for you. Please refer to comments inside the code for further information.

```
Sub Partial_Solution()
'... your code here

'... your loops start here

    'this way check which DashStyle is in your interest,
    'there are lots of different Dash styles of line
    'then you could remove it
    Debug.Print oShp.Line.DashStyle

    'and this way you can check the style before reading from shape
    'put the result here, like 5 which is msoLineDashDot style
    If oShp.Line.DashStyle = 5 Then

        '... your code here

    End If

'... rest of your code here
End Sub
```